# Wait for internet explorer to load everything?

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I am scraping a webpage, and waiting for internet explorer to get done loading but for some reason it is not. I'm trying to get a value on the page but the wait part is not waiting therefore the value comes back blank when there should be a value. **The IE page has done loading but the value for the elements on the page has not been loaded yet.** Is there a way to wait for all elements to get done loading before proceeding to next line of code? Here's my code:

```
Dim IE As Object 
Dim myvalue as string

IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.navigate("mypage")

While Not IE.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
End While

myValue = IE.document.getElementById("theValue").getAttribute("value")
Debug.Print(myValue)
```

Comment: Just a thought but have you first verified you can go to this page and use the built in debugger that most browsers have with F12?  You could test the javascript: "document.getElementById("theValue").getAttribute("value")" directly that way and ensure it is correct.

Comment: First of all **DO NOT** use `Application.DoEvents()` in order to keep your UI responsive! It is **bad practice!** Please read: [**Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

Comment: @djangojazz yes, the value is loaded after internet explorer has already been done loading therefore it skips the myValue part not getting the real value.

Comment: Since you're clearly using WinForms, create an instance of .NET's [**`WebBrowser` control**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) and subscribe to its [**`DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: i like to but webbrowser throws up alerts when going to the webpage and i've turn them off on the webbrowser and such but it is giving me complications therefore i'm going this direction. I could just pause the program for 5 secs but i do not want to wait the whole 5 sec if not needed.

Comment: What kind of alerts, and what kind of complications? Are they script error popups or alerts from the webpage itself?

Comment: no, not script error, alerts from the webpage stating you are using a old browser ect.

Comment: Hmm... Well, infact the `InternetExplorer` object has got a [**`DocumentComplete` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282(v=vs.85).aspx) too, question is how one should subscribe to it via COM.

Comment: If you add a reference to the `SHDocVw` COM object you should be able to treat everything as normal classes, thus also handle events. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66ahbe6y(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: not quit sure how to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **SHOULD NOT** use `Application.DoEvents()` in order to keep your UI responsive! I really can't stress this enough! More than often using it is a bad hack which only creates more problems than it solves.

For more information please refer to: [Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

The correct way is to use the [`InternetExplorer.DocumentComplete` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282(v=vs.85).aspx), which is raised when the page (or a sub-part of it, such an an `iframe`) is completely loaded. Here's a brief example of how you can use it:

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Add Reference...`
2. Go to the `COM` tab, find the reference called `Microsoft Internet Controls` and press `OK`.

   [image: Microsoft Internet Controls COM Reference]
3. Import the `SHDocVw` namespace to the file where you are going to use this, and create a class-level `WithEvents` variable of type `InternetExplorer` so that you can subscribe to the event with the [`Handles` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz(v=vs.90).aspx).

And *voila!*

```
Imports SHDocVw

Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents IE As New InternetExplorer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        IE.Navigate("http://www.google.com/")
    End Sub

    Private Sub IE_DocumentComplete(pDisp As Object, ByRef URL As Object) Handles IE.DocumentComplete
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully navigated to: " & URL.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Alternatively you can also subscribe to the event in-line using a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

```
Imports SHDocVw

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
        IE.Navigate("http://www.google.com/")

        AddHandler IE.DocumentComplete, Sub(pDisp As Object, ByRef URL As Object)
                                            MessageBox.Show("Successfully navigated to: " & URL.ToString())
                                        End Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @pokemon_Man : That was quick, did you make sure to test this properly with your code before accepting?