# Exception 0x800A01B6 using getElementById after the first load

Tags: vb.net, getelementbyid, ribbon

I have created a ribbon for Powerpoint with visual studio XML ribbon. This ribbon has a button that, simplifying, does this:

- opens an IE browser
- search an element (hiddenfield) in the code by his id
- get the value of this element
- Print the value in the actual slide

It works correctly the first time I click the button of my ribbon, but it throws an Exception 0x800A01B6 the following times I click the button.

This is the code executed when I click the button:

```
Dim oType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application")
If oType IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie = Nothing
    ie = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(oType), SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)

    If ie IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim oEmpty As Object = [String].Empty
        Dim oURL As Object = targetURL
        ie.AddressBar = False
        ie.MenuBar = False
        ie.ToolBar = 0
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Height = 800
        ie.Width = 1100
        ie.Navigate(oURL, oEmpty, oEmpty, oEmpty, oEmpty)
    End If

    Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        Sleep(1000)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

        Sleep(10000) ' 10 seconds for testing purpose

    Dim str As String = String.Empty
    Dim hdnstring As HTMLInputElement = ie.Document.getElementById("hdnstring")
    str = hdnstring.value

    DoSomething(str)

    ie.Quit()
    ie = Nothing
End If
```

This is the code of the website that opens (targetURL), the code remains identical in every load and only the hidden value changes:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="form1" id="form1">
        <input type="hidden" name="hdnstring" id="hdnstring" value="Get This String" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The second time (and following) I execute the function: the IE opens, the website fully loads, it waits 10 seconds and then I get an error in the line:

```
Dim hdnstring As HTMLInputElement = ie.Document.getElementById("hdnstring")
```

with Exception 0x800A01B6 message.

The most strange thing is that if I click viewsource in the IE contextual menu while the 10 seconds delay (the ones for testing purpose), it works perfect every time I click the button; but if I don't, the Exception 0x800A01B6 appers.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

**Error details image:**

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: Is there any more text in the exception?

Comment: only the line number where it fails

Comment: o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶f̶a̶i̶l̶s I added a screenshoot of detailed error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The type of the `Document` property is only resolved at run-time, so it's an `Object` until then (which is why you use what's called _late binding_, you do not know if the `getElementById` method exists or not). What you can try is casting the `Document` to an `IHTMLDocument3` object and see if that works: `DirectCast(ie.Document, IHTMLDocument3).getElementById("hdnstring")`.

Comment: You should also _**NEVER, EVER**_ call `Application.DoEvents()`. Instead, in this case, utilize the [**`DocumentComplete` event**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41989905/3740093).

Comment: Hi @VisualVincent, it works!!!! I had tried using IHTMLDocument3 before but not as you indicated. Thank you very much. Where do I have to send you a beer?

Comment: I don't use the Application.DoEvents(), I had it in the code only as a test. thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! I can buy a beer from the reputation points I get if you mark my answer below as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the `Document` property is only resolved at run-time, so it's an `Object` until then. This is why calling any methods in it results in the so-called late binding - you do not yet know if the `getElementById` method exists or not, so that has to be determined a run-time.

You most likely get the error because the `Document` is not of the [**`IHTMLDocument3` type**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752541(v=vs.85).aspx), which is the only document type that includes the `getElementById` method.

What you can try is casting the `Document` to an `IHTMLDocument3` interface. Since it inherits `IHTMLDocument` and `IHTMLDocument2` you can cast between them even if the document is actually one of the earlier types.

```
DirectCast(ie.Document, IHTMLDocument3).getElementById("hdnstring")
```