# WebBrowser fails on subsequent uses? WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted not work

Tags: vb.net, winforms

A VB.Net windows form using "WebBrowser" and HTMLDocument, HTMLTable, HTMLTableRow to retrieve innerText of the HTML Table row, column. It only works in the first time but fails on subsequent.

```
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim stockNo As String = ""
    Dim stockName String

    Dim doc As mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Dim table As mshtml.HTMLTable
    Dim rows As mshtml.HTMLTableRow

    doc = WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument
    table = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").item(0)
    For r = 3 To table.rows.length - 1
        rows = table.rows.item(r)

        Try
            stockNo = Replace(rows.cells(0).innerText, " ", "")
            stockName = Replace(rows.cells(1).innerText, " ", "")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error here: =====> " & ex.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine(rows.cells(0))              
        End Try
    Next r
End Sub
```

Here is the error when execute on 
    "rows.cells(0).innerText"

```
Error here: =====> System.NotSupportedException: 發生例外狀況於 HRESULT: 0x800A01B6 
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)    
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
```

Also try WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged but still not works. 
Any clue helps. Thanks.

Comment: The error message relates to late binding so the first thing to do would be to turn `Option Strict On` and make sure all casts and conversions are done explicitly. You will then get more explicit information if something is still not right.

Comment: Btw, you don't really need the `mshtml.HTMLDocument` for this. You can change the `InnerText` of a Cell using the `WebBrowser.Document` directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792555/exception-0x800a01b6-using-getelementbyid-after-the-first-load

Answer (score 1):

Two examples to perform the same task using the [mshtml.HTMLDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752641(v%3Dvs.85)) interface and the [WebBrowser Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document?view=netframework-4.7.2) object.

When handling the [DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) event, we first check its [ReadyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.ReadyState);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2). If it's not [WebBrowserReadyState.Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2), the current Document is still not ready to be parsed. Note that you can have more than one `HtmlDocument` per `HTML` Page (Frames and IFrames have their *personal* Document), so this event can be raised multiple times per page.

```
WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
```

To avoid the Late Bound warning or error, cast the WebBrowser **`HtmlDocument`** to a local variable of the same type. The same if you're using the **`mshtml.HTMLDocument`** interface:

```
Dim wbDoc As HtmlDocument = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser).Document
Dim htmlDoc As mshtml.HTMLDocument = DirectCast(wbDoc.DomDocument, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
```

As you can see in the two code snippets, the difference, when using either objects, is - in this case - almost non existent:

Using the **`mshtml.HTMLDocument`**:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then Return
    Dim startingRow As Integer = 3

    Dim wbDoc As HtmlDocument = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser).Document
    Dim htmlDoc As mshtml.HTMLDocument = DirectCast(wbDoc.DomDocument, mshtml.HTMLDocument)

    Dim firstTable As mshtml.HTMLTable = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").OfType(Of mshtml.HTMLTable)().FirstOrDefault()

    If firstTable IsNot Nothing Then
        For tableRow As Integer = startingRow To firstTable.rows.length - 1
            Dim row As mshtml.HTMLTableRow = DirectCast(firstTable.rows.item(tableRow), mshtml.HTMLTableRow)
            For col As Integer = 0 To 1
                Dim rowCell = DirectCast(row.cells.item(col), mshtml.HTMLTableCell)
                If rowCell IsNot Nothing Then
                    rowCell.innerText = rowCell.innerText?.Replace(" ", "")
                Else
                    'Decide what to do if the cell content is null
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Using the **`WebBrowser.Document`** directly:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then Return
    Dim startingRow As Integer = 3

    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser).Document
    Dim firstTable As HtmlElement = doc.GetElementsByTagName("TABLE").OfType(Of HtmlElement)().FirstOrDefault()

    If firstTable?.Children.Count > 0 Then
        For tableRow As Integer = startingRow To firstTable.Children.Count - 1
            Dim rowCells As HtmlElementCollection = firstTable.Children(tableRow).Children

            If rowCells Is Nothing Then Continue For
            For col As Integer = 0 To 1
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rowCells(col).InnerText) Then
                    rowCells(col).InnerText = rowCells(col).InnerText.Replace(" ", "")
                Else
                    'Decide what to do if the cell content is null
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, in my opinion, "**make sure all casts and conversions are done explicitly**. "  from **jmcilhinney** is right.

```
rows.cells(0).innerText    ===> Will fail on the subsequent use but do not know why the first time is OK

rows = table.rows.item(r)  ====> OK, if all casts and conversions are done explicitly
cell0 = rows.cells.item(0)
```

Thanks...