# CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") getelementbyname after navigate to another page

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

This will work fine.

(VB.NET)

```
Dim InternetExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With InternetExplorer
      .Visible = True
      .Navigate("www.test.com")
      .document.getElementsByName("value")(0).Value = "test"
end With
```

But if i navigate to another page and try to "getElementsByName" again, i will become this error "HRESULT: 0x800A01B6".

How can i fix it?

I am grateful for every suggestion.

Comment: Does vb.net account for the page load time? I think you need to set a timer to wait for the page to completely load so your element is available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Load Time is not the problem. I tried to navigate first and then to getelementsbyname. This works. But after the first call of the function getelementsbyname and then navigate, the function works no  more.

Comment: I'm actually very certain that the time it takes to download the page (load time) will cause issues. Maybe not this specific one, but you still ought to implement `DocumentCompleted`. See my following answer for an example and a more .NET friendly way of using the `InternetExplorer` object: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41989905/3740093

Comment: @Mickers : Loading time is not taken into account by any web browser as-is, and it's related to the browser, not the programming language (`InternetExplorer` is a standalone COM-object).