# Click Browser button from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have created a small application that takes inputs in the form and feeds it in to a form on a webpage. However I cannot work out a way to click the continue button. As no matter what I try it returns an error. This is what I am currently doing but it is returning an error.

```
'Define Store variable
        Dim Store As String
        Store = Me.TextBox1.Text
        'Define IP Address variable
        Dim IPAddress As String
        IPAddress = Me.TextBox2.Text
        'Define Username variable
        Dim Username As String
        Username = Me.TextBox3.Text
        'Define Password variable
        Dim Password As String
        Password = Me.TextBox4.Text

        ' Open Store Specific URL 1
        Dim IE As Object 'Internet explorer object
        Dim objCollection1 As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements
        Dim objCollection2 As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements
        Dim objCollection3 As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements
        Dim objCollection4 As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements
        Dim objCollection5 As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements
        Dim objCollectionA As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements

        'Create IE Object
        IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate("http://" & IPAddress & ":8080/")

        Do While IE.Busy
            Application.DoEvents() 'This allows the site to load first
        Loop

        'Find the field you are looking for and store it into the objCollection variable
        objCollection1 = IE.document.getelementsbyname("txtDeviceName")
        objCollection2 = IE.document.getelementsbyname("txtName")
        objCollection3 = IE.document.getelementsbyname("txtUID")
        objCollection4 = IE.document.getelementsbyname("txtPWD")
        objCollection5 = IE.document.getelementsbyname("txtOrgID")
        objCollectionA = IE.document.getelementsbyname("imgReregister")

        'Call element, and set value equal to the data you have from your form
        objCollection1(0).Value = "Value1"
        objCollection2(0).Value = "Value2"
        objCollection3(0).Value = Username
        objCollection4(0).Value = Password
        objCollection5(0).Value = "Value3"

        objCollectionA.getElementById("imgReregister").click()
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'getElementById' on type 'DispHTMLElementCollection' not found.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at WindowsApp1.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The button I am trying to click on the page in HTML looks like this

```
input name="imgReregister" title="Register" class="image" id="imgReregister" type="image" src="../images/next.gif"
```

Comment: Why do people keep using `Application.DoEvents()`, where do they get it from?! _**IT IS VERY BAD PRACTICE!**_ Add a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls` instead and subscribe to the [**`DocumentComplete` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Please see: [**Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)

Comment: As for your issue: You can only call `getElementById` on a document, not on a collection. Possibly you could access an element by its id via `objCollectionA("imgReregister")`, otherwise you'll just have to inspect the available methods of `Microsoft Internet Controls`.

Comment: Actually I forgot I have an answer which can give you guidance when adding a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls`, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989905/3740093