# How to access IE object's ReadyState in a VB application?

Tags: vb.net, object, internet-explorer, events, readystate

I'm creating a small application in VB.NET that opens a URL using an 'invisible' instance of Internet Explorer and I need to monitor the progress of the page as it loads in the background and then parse its contents.

I have the follow code working so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim oIE As Object
    oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.navigate("https://www.example.com/fetch.jsp?ID=XXXX")
    oIE.Visible = False
End Sub
```

IE runs as intended but I'm struggling for example to capture the ReadyState of the page as it's loading and would also appreciate any pointers on how to capture the html contents of the page after it loads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for internet explorer to load everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985826/wait-for-internet-explorer-to-load-everything)

Comment: Contrary to what's usually done in VBA, one should not wait in a loop for the loading to complete (and one most certainly _**SHOULD NOT**_ use `Application.DoEvents()` in such a loop to keep the UI responsive). The only correct way to run code after the page has been completely loaded is to subscribe to the `DocumentComplete` event (more on that in the duplicate I suggested).

Comment: @Visual Vincent, I suggest you to post your suggestion as an answer, So that user can mark it as an answer, if he thinks it is helpful. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT : If a question has already been answered before on Stack Overflow it should rather be flagged as a duplicate using the `flag` button underneath the post (or the `close` button if you have 3k+ rep). The OP can then choose to accept this duplicate if it answered his/her question. Doing so will close the question and include a link to the duplicate in the top. The question may also be closed for the same or another reason by four other 3k+ users voting to close it or by one user with a golden tag badge (duplicates only).

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT : If you want to know more I recommend reading [Privileges - flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841)